# Efficient way to fetch FireStore data into two fragments with a shared ViewModel

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Context: I have a `User` class that looks like this:

```
public class User {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private GeoPoint location;
    
    /* Constructor and getters */
    ...
}
```

and two `Fragment`s in which I'll display a list of the users' names in the first fragment using a `RecyclerView` and a `GoogleMap` that displays markers of the device location of the users in the second fragment. I'm using a shared `ViewModel` between these two fragments to supply the data needed. The `ViewModel` looks like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
public class UsersViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private List<User> users;
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Inject
    public UsersViewModel(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void fetchUsers(OnFetchDataCallback callback) {
        repository.getUsers(callback); 
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

In my repository class,

```
public class UserRepository {

    private final FirebaseFirestore db;

    @Inject
    public UserRepository(FirebaseFirestore db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers(OnFetchDataCallback callback) {
        db.collection("users")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot val,
                                    @FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : val) {
                        users.add(document.toObject(User.class);
                    }
                    callback.onFetchData(users);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I have a method called `getUsers()` that will do the actual fetching of users from a firestore database. I also created an interface callback that looks like this

```
public interface OnFetchDataCallback {
    void onFetchData(List<User> users);
}
```

so that later I can access the fetched users within my two fragments. In my first fragment,

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class DisplayUsersFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentDisplayUsersBinding binding;
    private UsersViewModel viewModel;
    private UsersAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UsersViewModel.class);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentDisplayUsersBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        binding.usersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        viewModel.fetchUsers(new OnFetchDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFetchData(List<User> users) {
                viewModel.setUsers(users);
                adapter = new UsersAdapter(viewModel.getUsers());
                binding.usersRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

I called the `fetchUsers()` and accessed the `List` of `users` inside the callback and set it to my `viewModel`'s `users` before constructing an adapter for my `RecyclerView` and providing it with the data it needs by calling `viewModel.getUsers()` and passing it as the constructor argument for the adapter.
Now, my problem here is that in my second fragment,

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class UsersMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private FragmentUsersMapBinding binding;
    private UsersViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UsersViewModel.class);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentUsersMapBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view,
                              @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.users_map_fragment_container, mapFragment)
            .commit()
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
         viewModel.fetchUsers(new OnFetchDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFetchData(List<User> users) {
                viewModel.setUsers(users);
                for (User user : viewModel.getUsers()) {
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(
                                    user.getLocation().getLatitude(),
                                    user.getLocation().getLongitude())
                                )
                                .title(user.getFirstname() + " " 
                                       user.getLastname()
                                )
                            );
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I called again `fetchUsers()` inside `onMapReady()` so that I can access inside its callback the users and use them to create markers in the map. Essentially, I tried to call `fetchUsers()` twice, but I think that there is a more efficient way to do this, but I have no idea how to handle this. Please help me, sorry my English is not good.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use live data in your ViewModel:
See the code given below:

```
@HiltViewModel
public class UsersViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private List<User> users;
    MutableLiveData<List<User>> usersLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Inject
    public UsersViewModel(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void fetchUsers() {
        repository.getUsers(new OnFetchDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFetchData(List<User> users) {
            usersLiveData.setValue(users);
            // you can observe this data after calling fetch users from your activity
            setUsers(users);
}); 
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

In the activity:

```
mViewModel.fetchUsers();
```

And in both fragments:

```
viewModel.usersLiveData.observe(this,{ list->
   // user your list here in both fragments
   // rather than fetch users on both fragments
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Another thing I did was change the scope of the ViewModel in the fragments. I realized I was using two different ViewModel instances because I scoped it within the two separate fragments, instead of their host activity.

Comment: ya, use a single ViewModel instance which will always remain the same for the whole activity lifecycle.